# App crashes when I press the textview

Tags: android, kotlin

I have the following TextView

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/LoginlinkLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical center_horizontal"
    android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="45sp"
    android:autoSizeMinTextSize="15sp"
    android:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
    android:text="@string/Loginlink"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:onClick="loginlinkLabelonClick"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

And this function

```
fun loginlinkLabelonClick(context:Context)
{
    val urlString="http://www.google.gr"
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(urlString)) intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
    intent.`package`="com.android.chrome"
    try
    {
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }
    catch(ex:ActivityNotFoundException)
    {
        intent.`package`= null
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

The error message:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.reviewer.reviewer, PID: 27809
>                     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method loginlinkLabelonClick(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for
>   android:onClick attribute defined on view class
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView with id 'LoginlinkLabel'
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:423)
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:380)
>                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6291)
>                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24931)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)

But as soon as I tap the textview the application crashes and I can't seem to find what's wrong.
I'm new to Java, kotlin and Android studio.
I had a previous experience with visual studio and c# and Java / kotlin feels a bit strange

Now I'm really trying to figure out how to open urls, but I'm having trouble getting it to work

Comment: What is the exception reported in the console?

Comment: Post your logcat by editing this post . The error should be there.

Comment: For fun use loginlinkLabelonClick(view : View)  instead of context : Context

Comment: Yep, the problem is exactly what's mentioned in my answer. You need a method whose sole argument is a view instance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually when you have a click method in the xml, the argument for the method in kotlin is a view instance, see more [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button#HandlingEvents). So your method should look like this:

```
fun loginlinkLabelonClick(view:View)
{

}
```